# Parse error: Unexpected end of file?

Tags: php

I've double-checked and everything looks closed to me, so I can't find the error. I just want to create a table to display mySQL data.

EDIT: I don't know why the closing tag was above the rest of the code, but I still get the error when it's in the correct place.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = “x”;
$password = “x”;
$dbname = “x”;

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Classroom”;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo “<tr><th>Building</th><th>Floor</th><th>Room</th><th>Instructional</th><th>Type<th>Size</th>  
<th>Seating</th><th>Decking</th><th>Access</th><th>Whiteboard</th><th>Chalkboard</th></tr>”;
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo “<tr><td>”.$row[“building”].”</td></tr>”;

}
} else {
echo (“0 results”);
}



mysqli_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that... but for starters, you have used `?>` before you are done with your code. It goes after all php code.

Comment: The source highlighting here shows the errors.  It looks like you have fancy quotes `“` in your code which PHP does not understand.  Make sure your strings are properly terminated.

Comment: @AhmedDaou So, not needing it and using it incorrectly are now synonymous?

Comment: Don't use a Word processor to code. Use a "code editor" to code with.

Comment: *"EDIT: I don't know why the closing tag was above the rest of the code, but I still get the error when it's in the correct place."* - It's the curly quotes. See the answer below given by `mopo922`. That answer was given first, and it gives an explanation.

Comment: You need to remove the last `}` in your file. An edit has been made to `mopo922`'s answer to that regard.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** As per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27974352/1

This should go at the very bottom:

```
?>
```

In fact, it isn't even required unless you're going to put some pure HTML after it. So leaving it out completely might save you headaches in the future.

---

However, several of your double-quotes look funky pasted here. You might check that they are just double-quotes, and not special characters.

These curly/smart quotes `“ ”` should be replaced by regular double quotes `"` throughout your code.

- Those alone will break its functionality and cause a parse/syntax error.

---

- **Edit:** As per your edit: You need to remove the last `}` in your file, the one just after `mysqli_close($conn);`. The number of braces do not match.

Comment: I think mopo is correct about the double-quotes.  Not sure why the down vote.

Comment: Thx all. I'm open to correction if anyone is willing to give it :)

Comment: @Mark What do you mean? I'm just saying if my answer is wrong, it's helpful to know why.

Comment: @Mark Actually Mark, even some of the much higher rep members occasionally overlook things, which is why we all like to chip in, in order to improve an answer. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, I misread. I thought OP was asking us to correct his original code with mopo's suggestions; updating an answer (as long as it doesn't change the intent) is good practice. (I upvoted mopo, his answer is good)

Comment: It all makes sense now :) I've done that before too. Thx @Mark

Comment: @mopo922 OP made an edit and I've made one to your answer in order to reflect that change and have instructed the OP to check your answer, as per a comment I left under the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
<?php

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "x";
$password = "x";
$dbname = "x";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Classroom";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "<tr><th>Building</th><th>Floor</th><th>Room</th><th>Instructional</th><th>Type<th>Size</th>  
<th>Seating</th><th>Decking</th><th>Access</th><th>Whiteboard</th><th>Chalkboard</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["building"]."</td></tr>";

}
}else{
echo("0 results");
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `?>` from all your documents, as it's unneeded, as PHP self closes at the end of a file.